# django 'Commande' object has no attribute '__name_

Tags: python, django

Hi stackoverflow people,

In my project i try to code a view which will manage am external api which will be used to fetch some datas, present them and store them in a database.

When i try to access to my view, i encounter the following error

**Traceback:**

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/commande/recherche

Django Version: 1.7.1
Python Version: 3.4.2
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'commands')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/commands-project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  87.                 response = middleware_method(request)
File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/commands-project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py" in process_request
  72.             if (not urlresolvers.is_valid_path(request.path_info, urlconf) and
File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/commands-project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in is_valid_path
  619.         resolve(path, urlconf)
File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/commands-project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  494.     return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve(path)
File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/commands-project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  345.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/commands-project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  345.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/commands-project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  224.             return ResolverMatch(self.callback, args, kwargs, self.name)
File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/commands-project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in callback
  231.         self._callback = get_callable(self._callback_str)
File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/commands-project/lib/python3.4/functools.py" in wrapper
  434.                 result = user_function(*args, **kwds)
File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/commands-project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in get_callable
  97.             mod = import_module(mod_name)
File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/commands-project/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py" in import_module
  109.     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "/home/user/workspace/Python/commands-project/project/commands/views.py" in <module>
  6. from .form import CommandesForm, CommandeForm
File "/home/user/workspace/Python/commands-project/project/commands/form.py" in <module>
  11. class CommandeForm(forms.ModelForm):
File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/commands-project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in __new__
  293.                                      opts.model.__name__)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /commande/recherche
Exception Value: 'Commande' object has no attribute '__name__'
```

My **models.py :**

```
from django.db import models


class Client(models.Model):
    client = models.IntegerField(null=True)


class Commandes(models.Model):
    date_debut = models.DateField()
    date_fin = models.DateField()
    id_groups = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    id_client = models.ForeignKey(Client)


class Commande(models.Model):
    id_flux = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    id_commande = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    id_client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
```

My **views.py** :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from http.client import HTTPConnection
from urllib.parse import urlparse, urlunparse
from .form import CommandesForm, CommandeForm
import requests

def resultat(request):
    return render(request, 'commands/resultat.html')


def recherche(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'Commandes' in request.POST:
            pass

        if 'Commande' in request.POST:
            pass
    else:
        formCommandes = CommandesForm()
       formCommande = CommandeForm()

    return render(request, 'commands/recherche.html', {'formCommandes': formCommandes })
```

And my **form.py**:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Commande, Commandes


class CommandesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Commandes()
        fields = ('date_debut', 'date_fin', 'id_groups')


class CommandeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Commande()
        fields = ('date_debut', 'date_fin', 'id_groups', 'id_client', 'id_flux',
                  'id_commande')
```

This is the following exception that i need to manage :
'Commande' object has no attribute '**name**'

I know that the '**name**' attribute is in the class not the instance.
The fact that i can't figure out is, why the exception is raise with 'Commande' object and not 'Commands' object

Comment: I guess the issue is with calling the model names. I mean: `model = Commandes()` should be `model = Commandes`

Comment: @karthikr Thanks for your answer, it was a really newbie mistakes. I'm unstuck now.